# Restlets, still active?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gwt, restlet

I'm struggling with Restlets since days...
One thing I have to complain about is the lack of documentation and (running)samples.
Most of the discussions/samples/threads I've found are from 2008/2009 which makes me ask if the procject is still active developed and used?

I need a communication technology which runs on Google App Engine and communicates with Android and some kind of webinterface (Jsp, GWT, Silverlight)...

Is Restlets the technology I have to choose,
or would you recommend something other?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Have you ever consider alternatives such as Jersey or even using Spring controller?

Comment: Are you looking at answer similar to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575744/creating-a-mobile-app-using-google-app-engine-and-gwt/13576518#13576518

Comment: did my answer helped? @stefan

Answer (score 1):

Even though the project started in 2005 and had the biggest part of its Restlet API design done in its early years, it is still very much active. Just have a look at the activity in StackOverFlow or GitHub.

We just published 'Restlet in Action' (Manning) last September after more than two years of development, along with version 2.1.0.

We have already started work on version 2.2 (Java 6 support, Jackson 2.1, etc.)

Comment: Is to buy the 'Restlet in Action' Book the only way to get started?
Because it seems that the documentation and the samples on your website are deprecated and not 100% running...

Comment: Not really. There can be some documentation gaps of course, but we try to fix them when reported. Have you tried this tutorial to integrate Android and GAE? http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1) Sencha Touch 2 native build or wrapping Sencha Touch 2 in Phonegap

2) Phoengap with mgwt

3) Titanium

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Restlet is still active, you may want to check the Github repository for the activity:

https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java

p.s.

We use Restlet with our consumer web application.