# Creating a mobile app using Google App Engine and GWT?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, mobile, mobile-application

I have a Google App Engine application with a front-end that was created using GWT. How would I go about creating a mobile app equivalent of this? In particular I would prefer to use GWT to create the front-end here as well. Does Google have any thing within GWT specifically designed for creating mobile apps? Is there already some existing structure in GWT which takes the front-end you've created and makes it scalable so that it can be easily transformed into a mobile app? Thank you much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a lot on whether you wish to build cross platform as in phonegap or keep it simple as in mobilewebapp example provided in sample folder in gwt zip file you download.

The mobilewebapp sample does not access smartphone features but will be accessible by browser on any mobile. phonegap or similar frameworks like titanium,sencha provide api to access smartphone features.

Fore more information -

http://www.sapandiwakar.in/technical/api-research-study-iphone-and-android-applications/

[Sencha Touch 2 native build vs wrapping Sencha Touch 2 in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642897/sencha-touch-2-native-build-vs-wrapping-sencha-touch-2-in-phonegap)

Comment: So by saying phonegap is cross platform, you're suggesting mobilewebapp isn't? Could you explain more? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Did the edited answer clear the doubts? You would need to list out whether you will need to scale your app to use smart phone feature and also note a mobilewebapp will always be slower than native app.

Answer (score 4):

You should also definitively check [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) + [gwt-phonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/). It's a cross platform gwt/phonegap [solution](http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/).